# How to save previous component DOM in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

Root.js

```
const Root = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
            <Route path="/main/:page" component={Main}/>
            <Route path="/detail/:name" component={Detail}/>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
);
export default Root;
```

Main in ItemList.js

```
render() {
    let count = 0;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map(function (data, i) {
                count++;
                return <Item data={data} key={count} order={count}/>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Item is  scroll bottom to(more view) append data( use ajax )

Item Click to Link to={item idx} and go to detail page

and back to page.. reset dom!

how to save dom?!?

Comment: The more you scroll down in the main, the more you got the data and moved to the detail page after loading
Will restore stacked data when you return and return to main again?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere.

Comment: you can't save DOM, but you can save data. Because on route change your state is destroyed, you need store your data outside of your Main component

Answer (score 0):

Save the data somewhere, so when you back to index, load the data in the page. [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) map help you to do all the things. And remember react is a 
data-driven framework. You get the data, you have the view.